# Remove query string - rewrite rule

Tags: string, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do i remove a query string from the end of a url?
To be more specific, this is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule example-(.*).html$ examples/view-example.php?param1=parameter&param2=$1&split=-
```

and I want this to return a 404 or a redirect to `www.mydomain.com/example-one.html` :

```
www.mydomain.com/example-one.html?param1=parameter&param2=one&split=-
```

This is what i tried, it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /examples/view-example\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1=parameter&param2=(.*)&split=-
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/example-%1.html$
```

I think that `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/example-%1.html$` isn't correct..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param1=parameter&param2=(.*)&split=-
RewriteRule ^/examples/view-example\.php$ http://mydomain.com/example-%1.html [R=301]
```

Though, I didn't understand what you wanted to do with `www.mydomain.com/example-one.html?param1=parameter&param2=one&split=-`